# xmlstartlet how can I insert <!--- comment --> line above node

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet, xml-comments

I want to add a commentline inside a xml file above the node 
using xmlstartlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
  </bookstore>
```

I like to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xml created by Stackoverflow-->
<bookstore>
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
  </bookstore>
```

I tried:

```
xmlstartlet ed -i /bookstore -t text -n <!--xml created by Stackoverflow--> -v "" test.xml
```

But gives error -bash: !--xml created by Stackoverflow--: event not found

hope someone can help.

Comment: I just read the xmlstarlet doc again and according to this, I did not find any command to modify comments.

Comment: unfortunately.. :( is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You can always use XSLT to solve this. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an XSLT-1.0 and above solution that can be applied by `xsltproc` or any other XSLT processor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template - copies all nodes without modification -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  
  
  <xsl:template match="/">                                     <!-- Match root element -->
    <xsl:comment> xml created by Stackoverflow </xsl:comment>  <!-- Add comment before root element -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />                 <!-- Apply identity template (and all other templates) -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output should be as expected.
If you could use XSLT-3.0, the *identity template* could be replaced by

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
```